# How to repin via Pinterest API?

Tags: pinterest

According to the [Pinterest API documentation for Pins](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/), you can create, edit, fetch, and delete pins. **What about Repinning?** There seems to be no mention of it in the official docs, yet numerous legitimate Pinterest marketing tools out there let you repin from *their* interface, which I assume means they're using the API.

Perhaps my assumption is wrong? Am I missing something obvious about how to repin an existing pin via the API?

As an example of a "legitimate Pinterest marketing tool" take Viralwoot, which lets you schedule a repin:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to know this, too. Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: @mayabelle I can say with 100% confidence that as of time of writing, Repinning is not something you can do via the official API. I don't know however if they gave a tool like Viralwoot special permissions.

Comment: Are you sure that the way other tools are doing it is actually a repin of that instance? Pinterest has been aggregating pin counts in their UI for a while now so maybe they tools are actually just creating new pins?

Comment: @mayabelle I have been struggling with this for a week now. I have been reading up on tons of API documentation and blogs etc... This is not possible at the moment. Even tools like Tailwind create original posts, no repins. I rewrote my tool to include several PDK.pin boxes so the user at least can at least repin a ton of links in one place. Not super efficient, but the only way it works.

Comment: Are you sure that tailwind creates new pins and not repin them ? because if that is the case I can easily write a program and save lot of money.